# Facebook Login UI as Fragment or View

Tags: android, facebook

When logging in with facebook an Activity is / can be launched (**com.facebook.LoginActivity**). In my case this is somewhat bad since I'm using a GLSurfaceView and since the graphics thread must be paused at the main activity's onPause-method, the transparent background of FB's activity causes problems.

Is it possible to avoid launching the login activity, using a fragment or view instead?

There is a **FacebookFragment** class but that's for package access only.

Using Facebook SDK 3.0.

**Edit**

The manifest entry for the activity is:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Since you control how the activity is added to your manifest, can you try removing the android:theme property? The LoginActivity is a critical part of the login workflow, and there's currently no fragment or view replacement for it.

Comment: There is no android:theme property set for the login activity. The activity's layout is defined in the sdk (com_facebook_login_activity_layout.xml) and contains only the progress bar.

Comment: Also, setting the android:theme to Theme.Black for the login activity doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I have tried the following with the Scrumptious sample app that ships with the SDK. In the AndroidManifest.xml for Scrumptious, there is:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

which gives the transparent background. If I change that block to:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

I get a black background for the activity, but everything else still works.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered why my LoginActivity had a black screen and this fixed it